# How to detect if the device is being used in WinRT application

Tags: c#, windows-8, app-store, windows-runtime

I'm investigating if it is possible in WinRT application:
When my WinRT application is CLOSED:

1. Get notified when user turn on the screen or unlock the screen or tap on the screen.
2. When the screen is turned off or locked, we can send the notify onto the screen or play a sound.

From the search result on Google, it seems only background task or push service have this ability to do the work even when the original application is CLOSED.
But I don’t if the background task can do the functions 1 and 2.
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do in your application?  Sometimes there's another way to achieve your goal without requiring the functionality you're asking for.

Comment: we are trying to create an alarm clock application, so we need the alarm can be triggered even when the application is cloed, or the screen is locked or turned off. we also want to konw if user is using the device currently. Thanks